# How do I decide which domain name will rank better for my keywords?

Tags: domains, seo

If I want to target the keyword phrases "make fun", "make fun of", and "how to make fun of", which is the best domain to choose of the following three and why?

- makefun.com
- makefunof.com
- howtomakefunof.com

Also, would it be good to purchase all three domain names and, if so, what should I do with them?

Answer (score 3):

You may wish to do your own keyword research to discover which of the three variants you've listed result in the most search requests, and how much competition there is for those keywords among existing domains.

Generally, though, the shorter the domain the better. This is because, if you're going to rank well for a term, it's most likely to be because you provide useful content that people will link to and remember. Short domains are simply easier to type and remember.

As I mentioned in my answer to your [other question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16873/exact-matching-phrase-domain-how-can-i-achieve-top-position-in-google), Google is considering removing the weight it places on keywords in domains. So, whatever domain you pick, you should optimise both the name and the content for humans first and Google second.

The only good reason to purchase multiple variants is to guard against people mistyping or misremembering them. Having multiple variations of a phrase redirecting to a single page does not add reputation or increase rankings for that page. It just makes it easier to land on by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I am in favor of nick. In-fact, You can get good rank for any of them. But shortest URL will be good for user to remember.

You must care in original content or their updated time period. Rest leave omn Google. It will best for you.